# I no longer see any link or button to add comments - is it my browser, or the site?

Tags: support, comments

I recently noticed that I do not see any way to add comments - on this site and also on wordpress.stackexchange.com.  I can't tell if that's to do with my point status on these sites, or if my recent upgrade to FF4 is a better explanation.

If I don't have 'comment' privileges, shouldn't I get a pop-up telling me so, when I attempt it, as is the case when up-voting questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least [50 reputation to comment](https://serverfault.com/privileges/comment). If you do not have enough reputation, you will not see the `add comment` link.  Most other [privileges](https://serverfault.com/privileges) (*e.g.* view votes, vote to close, etc.) will also not display their link/button until you've earned the appropriate amount of reputation.

Comment: unless it's my own question -- apparently.

Answer (score 0):

> "I no longer see any link or button to add comments"

I assume you mean, on your *own* questions and posts you have this privilege earlier.. see the [/faq](https://serverfault.com/faq) !

Comment: No - it's that I have enough points on other stackexchange sites to comment on other people's questions, and I never previously noted the difference between the privilege required to comment on my own questions, or answers - versus those of someone else.  Combine that with FF4 behaving badly for me, and I was confused about whether it was 'just me' or not.